# Knex not equal <> operator query

Tags: sql, knex.js

I'm trying to make query like:

> "SELECT * ... WHERE deleted <> 1"

I found one solution:

> .whereRaw("deleted <> ?", [1]);

But can I use **.where** (**.whereNot**) methods for this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<>` and `!=` both mean not equal, and `!=` is an alias for the **standard** `<>` operator.

`!=` may not exist in old version of MySQL, but normally you have no need to pay attention to this, as for knex documentation, it's just an example which tried to explain `knex.raw`...

`whereNot` is OK.

Answer (score 7):

You can use directly knex.js [whereNot](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereNot) method as in the following:

```
knex('table_name').whereNot('deleted', 1)
```

which translates to:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE NOT deleted = 1
```